# Custom image in a linked post not working through API for LinkedIn profile

Tags: linkedin-api

## linkedin

Hi,

When we replace preview of a URL with a custom image, recently we have seen that they have stopped getting posted with the custom image on LinkedIn profiles through API. It works on LinkedIn companies.

Is it a temporary bug or some change of which we were not informed?

An example given below.

Thanks.

```
{
 "author": "urn:li:person:9DeFJQSxT0",
 "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
 "specificContent": {
 "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
 "shareCommentary": {
 "text": "hello amit recurpost.com test"
 },
 "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
 "media": [
 {
 "status": "READY",
 "description": {
 "text": "Kickstart your social media marketing and manage multiple social accounts from a single dashboard with one powerful and affordable social media scheduling tool."
 },
 "originalUrl": "https://recurpost.page.link/awqx",
 "thumbnails": [
 {
 "url": "https://rpdevelopers.blob.core.windows.net/imagesdev/1589179465_5eb8f44941d96.jpeg"
 }
 ],
 "title": {
 "text": "Social Media Scheduler with Repeating Schedules | RecurPost"
 }
 }
 ]
 }
 },
 "visibility": {
 "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
 }
}
```